# Error running dotnet core 2.1 app on Alpine image

Tags: docker, .net-core, alpine-linux

Running Docker on a Win10 machine. Linux containers enabled. My app runs fine on Windows and Debian images but when I switched to Alpine I get this error

`PS C:\Code\TestApp> docker run -it testapp:latest
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"/app/TestApp\": stat /app/TestApp: no such file or directory": unknown.`

I've tried changing the Entrypoint to match some examples but no dice.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-runtime-deps-alpine3.7 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk-alpine3.7 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY TestApp/TestApp.csproj TestApp/
RUN dotnet restore TestApp/TestApp.csproj
COPY . .

WORKDIR /src/TestApp
RUN dotnet build TestApp.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish TestApp.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
# This is for Windows and Debian images
# ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestApp.dll"]

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/TestApp"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some debug information in your different stages of this multi-stage build:

```
RUN ls -alrth /app
```

(after each `COPY` or `RUN dotnet` commands)

And make sure to build it with a name and tag different from your first builds for Windows, in order to be sure to not try a Windows-built image in your Linux environment.

```
docker build -t testApp-linux ...
```

Comment: Very helpful! It's failing on `dotnet publish` with error `/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.200/NuGet.targets(114,5): warning : Unable to find a project to restore!`

Comment: @user3953989 OK, at least it is starting ;) But that seems a dotnet usage/configuration issue.